# Can one become addicted to learning?

Tags: learning, addiction

**Is it possibly to become addicted to learning?**

What drives this addiction and how can it be controlled?

Note:
I'm not sure this is the right exchange for this question... Its the best fit as far as I can see though.

Comment: I'm still seeking an answer. If anyone has any input I would love to hear it.

Comment: You can be addicted to anything which brings pleasure. Does studying bring any form of pleasure? What research have you conducted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any form of excessive secretion of dopamine, can not be good, be it drugs, learning, sex etc. workaholism is a form learning addiction,  workaholism is said to be as an addiction
very similar to alcoholism. Workaholic as a “person whose pleasure from learning things at work has become so extreme, that it indicates clear disturbances with his/her personal happiness, bodily health, and interpersonal relations, and with his smooth social functioning” . Therefore,  there are some perspectives related to workaholism. workaholism at least initially was formulated to be referred as addictive process (Sussman, 2012).
 Negative side effects of workaholism or the strive or need to constantly work towards gaining knowledge may include subjective emotional sorrow or feeling of “burned out” (Sussman, 2012).

Based on that search,
these authors induced that addiction includes: 
(a) engagement in the behavior to achieve
appetitive effects
 (b) preoccupation with the behavior 
(c) temporary satiation
 (d)loss of control
 (e) suffering negative consequences
hope my answer helped. if you want to read in depth on this. do refer to the reference for article.
**reference :  Sussman, S. (2012). Workaholism: A Review. Journal Of Addiction Research & Therapy. doi: 10.4172/2155-6105.s6-001**

Answer (score 1):

According to [Psychology Today](https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/in-excess/201602/addiction-to-studying),

> There is little research and no generally accepted definition of study addiction to date, such behavior has been analyzed within research into workaholism. The 'work addiction’ (i.e., workaholism) perspective, helped Dr. Cecilie Andreassen and her colleagues define study addiction (i.e., learning addiction) in a 2014 article of the Journal of Managerial Psychology as: *“Being overly concerned with studying, to be driven by an uncontrollable studying motivation, and to put so much energy and effort into studying that it impairs private relationships, spare-time activities, and/or health”.*

The journal article mentioned is actually from the *journal of behavioral addictions*:

Atroszko, P. A., Andreassen, C. S., Griffiths, M. D., & Pallesen, S. (2015). Study addiction—A new area of psychological study: Conceptualization, assessment, and preliminary empirical findings. *Journal of behavioral addictions, 4*(2), 75-84. https://doi.org/10.1556/2006.4.2015.007